# How to create Microsoft Flow Template?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

We are trying to create an approval Flow which could be started for a document in any document library.

In past we could create Workflow Template from SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio solution.

Is there any resouces or dcoumentation available to create a Flow template?

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a flow to the gallery, but that is public: [instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/publish-a-template).

If that isn't what you are looking for, you can export the flow for import and reuse. Or "Share" it with everyone, who can then use "Save As" to move it.

Comment: Question is on how to create a template to make it reusable and probably share using market place.